# Removing contour using Marvin Framework in Java

Tags: java, image-processing, pattern-recognition, marvin-framework

I'm using [Marvin Framework](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/index.html) to get the veins pattern, but I don't know how to remove the leaf contour

I'm doing the following : 
(Each function calls its corresponding Marvin Plugin.) :

```
    MarvinImage source = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("source.jpg");

    MarvinImage gsImage = grayscaleImage(source);

    MarvinImage blImage1 = blurEffect(gsImage.clone(),1);

    MarvinImage blImage2 = blurEffect(blImage1.clone(), 13);

    MarvinImage difi = subtract(blImage2.clone(), blImage1.clone());

    difi = invertC(difi.clone());

    difi = closingEffect(difi.clone());

    difi = MarvinColorModelConverter.binaryToRgb(difi.clone());

    difi = reduceNoise(difi.clone());

    difi = invertC(difi.clone());

    MarvinImageIO.saveImage(difi, "result.jpg");
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see how you could do this without identifying the background and preventing the background from being included when blurred.

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a simple approach that may help you. It just removes the leaf borders from left to right and from right to left.

The only implication is the leaf orientation. I've rotated your output image manually. However, I think you should consider leafs in that position for better analysis.

**leaf_rotated.jpg:**

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/other/leaf_rotated.jpg))</sub>

**leaf_rotated_out.jpg:**

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/other/leaf_rotated_out.jpg))</sub>

**SOURCE CODE:**

```
public class LeafTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MarvinImage image = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./res/leaf_rotated.jpg");
        removeBorder(image);
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(image, "./res/leaf_rotated_out.jpg");
    }

    private static void removeBorder(MarvinImage image){

        // left to right
        for(int y=0; y<image.getHeight(); y++){
            for(int x=0; x<image.getWidth(); x++){

                if(image.getIntComponent0(x, y) > 10){

                    for(int x2=x; x2<image.getWidth() && x2 < x+40; x2++){
                        image.setIntColor(x2, y, 0,0,0);
                    }

                    x=0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // right to left
        for(int y=0; y<image.getHeight(); y++){
            for(int x=image.getWidth()-1; x>=0; x--){

                if(image.getIntComponent0(x, y) > 10){

                    for(int x2=x; x2>=0 && x2 > x-40; x2--){
                        image.setIntColor(x2, y, 0,0,0);
                    }

                    x=image.getWidth()-1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i already tried this, but the goal is to remove the contour using marvin plugins...

Comment: What do you mean with "goal"? Is it an exercise? What is the definition of the problem?

Comment: I think we should subtract its convex hull from the black-and-white image. But I don't know how to do it correctly in this framework.